# Directly Pick Item on DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, focus, cell

Anyone can help me to find an add-on or control for C#

[image: How can we focus on a cell and has extra button]

I have been googling around for the last few days.
How can we focus on a cell and has extra button to pick item or open other form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can set the property ColumnType for this column to DataGridViewButtonColumn.
Its an ugly button, but its a button.

Another option is using a contextmenuitem.

about your comment, using a contextmenustrip on a DataGridView is not so hard:
1. drop a contextmenuStrip from the toolbox onto your form
2. Add a toolStripMenu and enter a text, for example "pick something"
3. set the property "ContextMenuStrip" from the DataGridview to this new contextMenuStrip
4. in the Click event of the toolStripMenu you can write whatever code you need

Comment: Hi @GuidoG, I dont get how we can implement contextmenuitemin the data grid's cell. Yes its an ugly button, but quite important in my project :)

Comment: @user2936719 I have edited my answer with info on contextMenuItem

Comment: The  button is an much easier solution though